# C loop is not iterating through string properly

Tags: c, string, loops, iteration

I am using the following method to iterate through a string:

```
char is_words(char *word)
{
  if (word != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(word)-1; i++) {
      char c = word[i];
      printf("c is: %c\n", c);
      if (!isalpha(c) || !isspace(c)) {
        return c;
      }
    }
  }
  return 'a';
}
```

Yet when use it, it only prints out "c is X", where X is the first letter of the string.  Why does it not iterate through the entire string?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. e.g. How do we know that the string isn't something like "123" which will cause the first `return` to execute?

Comment: Probably need to replace `||` with `&&` in the `if` statement.

Comment: `return` terminates function execution and returns the control to the caller function.

Comment: Notice that you are computing `strlen(word)` on *each* iteration. There are better ways

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch fixed thank you!

Comment: @user1519226 If your problem is fixed, you could accept one answer so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Replace this piece of code :

```
if (!isalpha(c) || !isspace(c)) {
    return c;
}
```

with :

```
if (!isalpha(c) && !isspace(c)) {
    return c;
}
```

as you want to return when ***both*** of the following conditions are true :

- `c` is not an alphabetic character
- `c` is not a space

Your condition right now returns a character (and consequently ends the function) ***either*** *if it is not alphabetic* ***or*** *if it is not space*. So by giving a string of letters, the function will consider them as non-spaces, and therefore will return at the first character.

**2.** Also replace the loop condition :

```
for (int i = 0; i<strlen(word)-1; i++)
```

with :

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
```

as by examining characters up to `strlen(word)-1`, you will not examine the last character.

Answer (score 1):

it returns C in this line

```
 if (!isalpha(c) || !isspace(c)) {
        return c;
 }
```

function finishes execution after returning a value

---

learn how to use &&  and ||

some explanation

if `c` is abc symbol -  `isalpha(c) = true , isspace(c) = false`

```
true || false = true
```

if `c` is space symbol

```
isalpha(c) = false , isspace(c) = true

false || true = true
```

if `c` is digit  you l get false and print 1 more symb

Answer (score -2):

Ok, what do you want to do,
1. if you wanna print only letters,
Replace return with "continue"

Comment: The OP wants to return if he meets a character which is not alphabetic or space. If he replaces `return` with `continue`, this will not happen.